# Como Ingresar el nombre de usuario en un reportviewer en c# con variable de session

Tags: c#, reportviewer

necesito de su ayuda, Como puedo Ingresar el nombre de usuario que esta activo en un reportviewer en c# con variable de session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se solvento creando un parametro en el diseño llamado Usuario   y bajo codigo donde muestro el diseño  realice lo siguiente:

ReportParameter usuario = new ReportParameter("Usuario", Session["Usuario"].ToString());

```
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(usuario);
```

Comment: Para la siguiente pregunta, agrega tu codigo y se mas especifico en tu duda, saludos.